# Mahout : How to convert custom document in SparseVector format for using LDA

Tags: mahout, lda

I have a set of documents in which each line has certain number of Strings seperated with "\t|\t". Each String(may contain spaces in between) is a indivisible dictionary item. Now I have to use LDA to find the correletaion between these documents with respect to each dictionsr word(String in my vocab).

Please guide me how can I convert these documents to spares vector format and then how to apply LDA on them?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best links that i have found that might answer your queries.

http://www.theglassicon.com/computing/machine-learning/running-lda-algorithm-mahout